# type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'

Tags: python, datetime, python-import

I have a script with the following import:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and a piece of code where I call:

```
datetime.fromisoformat(duedate)
```

Sadly, when I run the script with an instance of Python 3.6, the console returns the following error:

> AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'

I tried to run it from two instances of anaconda (3.7 and 3.8) and it works nice and smooth.
I supposed there was an import problem so I tried to copy datetime.py from anaconda/Lib to the script directory, with no success.

The `datetime.py` clearly contains the class `datetime` and the method `fromisoformat` but still it seems unlinked. I even tried to explicitly link the `datetime.py` file, with the same error:

```
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
vendor_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'libs')
sys.path.append(vendor_dir+os.path.sep+"datetime.py")
```

Can you help me? My ideas are over...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The issue here is actually that `fromisoformat` is not available in Python versions older than 3.7, you can see that clearly stated in the documenation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat).

```
Return a date corresponding to a date_string given in the format YYYY-MM-DD:
>>>

>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.fromisoformat('2019-12-04')
datetime.date(2019, 12, 4)

This is the inverse of date.isoformat(). It only supports the format YYYY-MM-DD.

New in version 3.7.
```

Comment: doh... do you know an alternative for older python 3's instances?

Comment: perhaps [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) is what you are looking for

Comment: isoformat() seems to have the opposite effect since it translates to ISO8601 format. I'll look for alternative solutions. Thanks btw

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and found this:

https://pypi.org/project/backports-datetime-fromisoformat/

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime, time
>>> from backports.datetime_fromisoformat import MonkeyPatch
>>> MonkeyPatch.patch_fromisoformat()

>>> datetime.fromisoformat("2014-01-09T21:48:00-05:30")
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 21, 48, tzinfo=-05:30)

>>> date.fromisoformat("2014-01-09")
datetime.date(2014, 1, 9)

>>> time.fromisoformat("21:48:00-05:30")
datetime.time(21, 48, tzinfo=-05:30)
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Works great, but is there a function like `timedelta` in `datetime.datetime`. How can you increment the date here ?

Comment: It works just like you would expect. Since you still import `datetime` and just update the `fromisoformat` the rest stays unchanged.

Answer (score 12):

You should refactor `datetime.fromisoformat('2021-08-12')` to use `datetime.strptime` like this:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime                                                                                                                                                          

In [2]: datetime.strptime("2021-08-08", "%Y-%m-%d")                                                                                                                                           
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 8, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python version 3.6 and older don't have the `fromisoformat()` methods - as mentioned in other documentation - **both** `datetime.fromisoformat` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat)) and `date.fromisoformat` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)) are not available.

You can use this code I wrote to implement this in Python 3.6. I prefer not to install additional dependencies for functions I hardly use - in my case, I only use it in a test.

### Python3.6 and below

```
from datetime import datetime

time_expected = datetime.now()
time_actual = datetime.strptime(time_actual.isoformat(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
assert time_actual == time_expected
```

### Python3.7+

```
from datetime import datetime

time_expected = datetime.now()
time_actual = datetime.fromisoformat(time_expected.isoformat())
assert time_actual == time_expected
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem, or the same error message, anyway, even though I am running Python 3.11.6. In my case, the real issue is confusion over the import name and the class name. To wit:

`(venv) rob@robuntuflex:~/proj/pracMonFront$ python
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  8 2023, 05:06:43) [GCC 13.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat("2023-10-07T10:20:38")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2023-10-07T10:20:38")
datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 7, 10, 20, 38)`

HTH

/rob