# Python 3.11.3 and datetime has no attribute fromisoformat

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, isodate

[Starting from 3.7, `datetime` has attribute `fromisoformat`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60266554/3416774). Here is my script:

```py
import datetime
import sys
print(sys.version)
test = datetime.fromisoformat('2023-11-30T11:00:00.000Z')
print(test)
```

The result:

```
3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ganuo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,  
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
  File "C:\Users\ganuo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\ganuo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\ganuo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main   
    run()
  File "c:\Users\ganuo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__") 
  File "c:\Users\ganuo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\ganuo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,  
  File "c:\Users\ganuo\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\QC supplements\Code\Apps\Automation\events.py", line 4, in <module>
    test = datetime.fromisoformat('2023-11-30T11:00:00.000Z')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'
```

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` is the module. `datetime` is the class.

```
from datetime import datetime
```

see

```
$ python
Python 3.11.6 (main, Nov 14 2023, 09:36:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2023-11-30T11:00:00.000Z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2023-11-30T11:00:00.000Z')
datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 30, 11, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>>
```

try that.

Comment: `import datetime.datetime`  will not work, datetime is not a submodule.

Comment: has been removed

Answer (score 0):

The [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromisoformat#) has 6 objects: `date`, `datetime`, `time`, `timedelta`, `timezone`, `tzinfo`. You need to import the [`datetime` **object**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromisoformat#datetime.datetime) in order to use the [`fromisoformat()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=fromisoformat#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

```py
from datetime import datetime
```